# JspC in jboss 4.2 distribution

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

Where can I find the org.apache.jasper.JspC class in the JBoss 4.2 distribution (exactly a 4.2.2.GA one)?
Thanks

Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\all\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\jbossweb.jar

This site is your friend: [findjar](http://www.findjar.com)